# how to call NdisOpenAdapterEx or the alternative outside the ProtocolBindAdapter routine?

Tags: windows, driver, wdk, ndis, wdm

I am porting the famous packet capture software -- WinPcap from NDIS 5.0 to NDIS 6.x. I tried to translate every NDIS 5.0 function to its 6.0 version. In WinPcap sourcecode function NdisOpenAdapter is called by NPF_OpenAdapter in Openclos.c. I translated it to NdisOpenAdapterEx for NDIS 6.0. But I cannot find a way to set the 4th parameter BindContext. 
The delcaration of NdisOpenAdapterEx can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563715(v=vs.85).aspx

Also MS said "A protocol driver must call NdisOpenAdapterEx from its ProtocolBindAdapterEx function. NDIS fails any attempt to call NdisOpenAdapterEx outside the context of ProtocolBindAdapterEx.". So it seems that NdisOpenAdapterEx cannot be called in NPF_OpenAdapter. it must be called in the NPF_BindAdapterEx function. I substituted the driver npf.sys with my own version, started Wireshark (a packet capture frontend), set breakpoints in NPF_BindAdapterEx and found NPF_BindAdapterEx was never called before NPF_OpenAdapter. So it is impposible for me to get the BindContext paramters before calling NdisOpenAdapterEx.

I just want to imgrate WinPcap to NDIS 6.0 with modifications as small as possible. And how to solve this problem？

Here is the code of Openclos.c

```
    /*
* Copyright (c) 1999 - 2005 NetGroup, Politecnico di Torino (Italy)
* Copyright (c) 2005 - 2010 CACE Technologies, Davis (California)
* All rights reserved.
*
* Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
* modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
* are met:
*
* 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
* notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
* 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
* notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
* documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
* 3. Neither the name of the Politecnico di Torino, CACE Technologies 
* nor the names of its contributors may be used to endorse or promote 
* products derived from this software without specific prior written 
* permission.
*
* THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
* "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
* LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
* A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT
* OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
* SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
* LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
* DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
* THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
* (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
* OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
*
*/

#include "stdafx.h"

#include <ntddk.h>
#include <ndis.h>

#include "debug.h"
#include "packet.h"
#include "..\..\Common\WpcapNames.h"


static
VOID NPF_ReleaseOpenInstanceResources(POPEN_INSTANCE pOpen);

static NDIS_MEDIUM MediumArray[] =
{
    NdisMedium802_3,
    //  NdisMediumWan,
    NdisMediumFddi, NdisMediumArcnet878_2, NdisMediumAtm, NdisMedium802_5
};

#define NUM_NDIS_MEDIA  (sizeof MediumArray / sizeof MediumArray[0])

//Itoa. Replaces the buggy RtlIntegerToUnicodeString
// void PacketItoa(UINT n, PUCHAR buf)
// {
//  int i;
//  for(i=0;i<20;i+=2){
//      buf[18-i]=(n%10)+48;
//      buf[19-i]=0;
//      n/=10;
//  }
// }

/// Global start time. Used as an absolute reference for timestamp conversion.
struct time_conv G_Start_Time =
{
    0, {0, 0},
};

ULONG g_NumOpenedInstances = 0;

BOOLEAN NPF_StartUsingBinding(IN POPEN_INSTANCE pOpen)
{
    ASSERT(pOpen != NULL);
    ASSERT(KeGetCurrentIrql() == PASSIVE_LEVEL);

    NdisAcquireSpinLock(&pOpen->AdapterHandleLock);

    if (pOpen->AdapterBindingStatus != ADAPTER_BOUND)
    {
        NdisReleaseSpinLock(&pOpen->AdapterHandleLock);
        return FALSE;
    }

    pOpen->AdapterHandleUsageCounter++;

    NdisReleaseSpinLock(&pOpen->AdapterHandleLock);

    return TRUE;
}

VOID NPF_StopUsingBinding(IN POPEN_INSTANCE pOpen)
{
    ASSERT(pOpen != NULL);
    //
    //  There is no risk in calling this function from abobe passive level 
    //  (i.e. DISPATCH, in this driver) as we acquire a spinlock and decrement a 
    //  counter.
    //
    //  ASSERT(KeGetCurrentIrql() == PASSIVE_LEVEL);

    NdisAcquireSpinLock(&pOpen->AdapterHandleLock);

    ASSERT(pOpen->AdapterHandleUsageCounter > 0);
    ASSERT(pOpen->AdapterBindingStatus == ADAPTER_BOUND);

    pOpen->AdapterHandleUsageCounter--;

    NdisReleaseSpinLock(&pOpen->AdapterHandleLock);
}

VOID NPF_CloseBinding(IN POPEN_INSTANCE pOpen)
{
    NDIS_EVENT Event;
    NDIS_STATUS Status;

    ASSERT(pOpen != NULL);
    ASSERT(KeGetCurrentIrql() == PASSIVE_LEVEL);

    NdisInitializeEvent(&Event);
    NdisResetEvent(&Event);

    NdisAcquireSpinLock(&pOpen->AdapterHandleLock);

    while (pOpen->AdapterHandleUsageCounter > 0)
    {
        NdisReleaseSpinLock(&pOpen->AdapterHandleLock);
        NdisWaitEvent(&Event, 1);
        NdisAcquireSpinLock(&pOpen->AdapterHandleLock);
    }

    //
    // now the UsageCounter is 0
    //

    while (pOpen->AdapterBindingStatus == ADAPTER_UNBINDING)
    {
        NdisReleaseSpinLock(&pOpen->AdapterHandleLock);
        NdisWaitEvent(&Event, 1);
        NdisAcquireSpinLock(&pOpen->AdapterHandleLock);
    }

    //
    // now the binding status is either bound or unbound
    //

    if (pOpen->AdapterBindingStatus == ADAPTER_UNBOUND)
    {
        NdisReleaseSpinLock(&pOpen->AdapterHandleLock);
        return;
    }

    ASSERT(pOpen->AdapterBindingStatus == ADAPTER_BOUND);

    pOpen->AdapterBindingStatus = ADAPTER_UNBINDING;

    NdisReleaseSpinLock(&pOpen->AdapterHandleLock);

    //
    // do the release procedure
    //
    NdisResetEvent(&pOpen->NdisOpenCloseCompleteEvent);

    // Close the adapter
    Status = NdisCloseAdapterEx(pOpen->AdapterHandle);

    if (Status == NDIS_STATUS_PENDING)
    {
        TRACE_MESSAGE(PACKET_DEBUG_LOUD, "Pending NdisCloseAdapter");
        NdisWaitEvent(&pOpen->NdisOpenCloseCompleteEvent, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        TRACE_MESSAGE(PACKET_DEBUG_LOUD, "Not Pending NdisCloseAdapter");
    }

    NdisAcquireSpinLock(&pOpen->AdapterHandleLock);
    pOpen->AdapterBindingStatus = ADAPTER_UNBOUND;
    NdisReleaseSpinLock(&pOpen->AdapterHandleLock);
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------

NTSTATUS NPF_OpenAdapter(IN PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, IN PIRP Irp)
{
    PDEVICE_EXTENSION DeviceExtension;
    POPEN_INSTANCE Open;
    PIO_STACK_LOCATION IrpSp;
    NDIS_STATUS Status;
    NDIS_STATUS ErrorStatus;
    UINT i;
    PUCHAR tpointer;
    PLIST_ENTRY PacketListEntry;
    NTSTATUS returnStatus;

    NET_BUFFER_LIST_POOL_PARAMETERS PoolParameters;
    NDIS_OPEN_PARAMETERS OpenParameters;
    NET_FRAME_TYPE FrameTypeArray[2] =
    {
        NDIS_ETH_TYPE_802_1X, NDIS_ETH_TYPE_802_1Q
    };

    //  
    //  Old registry based WinPcap names
    //
    //  WCHAR               EventPrefix[MAX_WINPCAP_KEY_CHARS];
    //  UINT                RegStrLen;

    TRACE_ENTER();

    DeviceExtension = DeviceObject->DeviceExtension;

    IrpSp = IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation(Irp);

    //  allocate some memory for the open structure
    Open = ExAllocatePoolWithTag(NonPagedPool, sizeof(OPEN_INSTANCE), '0OWA');

    if (Open == NULL)
    {
        // no memory
        Irp->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
        IoCompleteRequest(Irp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);
        return STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
    }

    RtlZeroMemory(Open, sizeof(OPEN_INSTANCE));

    //  
    //  Old registry based WinPcap names
    //
    //  //
    //  // Get the Event names base from the registry
    //  //
    //  RegStrLen = sizeof(EventPrefix)/sizeof(EventPrefix[0]);
    //
    //  NPF_QueryWinpcapRegistryString(NPF_EVENTS_NAMES_REG_KEY_WC,
    //      EventPrefix,
    //      RegStrLen,
    //      NPF_EVENTS_NAMES_WIDECHAR);
    //

    Open->DeviceExtension = DeviceExtension;

    NdisZeroMemory(&PoolParameters, sizeof(NET_BUFFER_LIST_POOL_PARAMETERS));
    PoolParameters.Header.Type = NDIS_OBJECT_TYPE_DEFAULT;
    PoolParameters.Header.Revision = NET_BUFFER_LIST_POOL_PARAMETERS_REVISION_1;
    PoolParameters.Header.Size = sizeof(PoolParameters);
    PoolParameters.ProtocolId = NDIS_PROTOCOL_ID_TCP_IP;
    PoolParameters.ContextSize = 0;
    PoolParameters.fAllocateNetBuffer = TRUE;
    PoolParameters.PoolTag = NPCAP_ALLOC_TAG;

    Open->PacketPool = NdisAllocateNetBufferListPool(NULL, &PoolParameters);
    if (Open->PacketPool == NULL)
    {
        TRACE_MESSAGE(PACKET_DEBUG_LOUD, "Failed to allocate packet pool");

        ExFreePool(Open);
        Irp->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
        IoCompleteRequest(Irp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);
        return STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
    }

    //  //  Allocate a packet pool for our xmit and receive packets
    //  NdisAllocatePacketPool(
    //      &Status,
    //      &Open->PacketPool,
    //      TRANSMIT_PACKETS,
    //      sizeof(PACKET_RESERVED));
    // 
    //  if (Status != NDIS_STATUS_SUCCESS) {
    // 
    //      TRACE_MESSAGE(PACKET_DEBUG_LOUD, "Failed to allocate packet pool");
    // 
    //      ExFreePool(Open);
    //      Irp->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
    //      IoCompleteRequest(Irp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);
    //      return STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
    //  }

    NdisInitializeEvent(&Open->WriteEvent);
    NdisInitializeEvent(&Open->NdisRequestEvent);
    NdisInitializeEvent(&Open->NdisWriteCompleteEvent);
    NdisInitializeEvent(&Open->DumpEvent);
    NdisAllocateSpinLock(&Open->MachineLock);
    NdisAllocateSpinLock(&Open->WriteLock);
    Open->WriteInProgress = FALSE;

    for (i = 0; i < g_NCpu; i++)
    {
        NdisAllocateSpinLock(&Open->CpuData[i].BufferLock);
    }

    NdisInitializeEvent(&Open->NdisOpenCloseCompleteEvent);

    //  list to hold irp's want to reset the adapter
    InitializeListHead(&Open->ResetIrpList);

    //  Initialize the request list
    KeInitializeSpinLock(&Open->RequestSpinLock);
    InitializeListHead(&Open->RequestList);

    //
    // Initialize the open instance
    //
    //Open->BindContext = NULL;
    Open->bpfprogram = NULL;    //reset the filter
    Open->mode = MODE_CAPT;
    Open->Nbytes.QuadPart = 0;
    Open->Npackets.QuadPart = 0;
    Open->Nwrites = 1;
    Open->Multiple_Write_Counter = 0;
    Open->MinToCopy = 0;
    Open->TimeOut.QuadPart = (LONGLONG)1;
    Open->DumpFileName.Buffer = NULL;
    Open->DumpFileHandle = NULL;
#ifdef HAVE_BUGGY_TME_SUPPORT
    Open->tme.active = TME_NONE_ACTIVE;
#endif // HAVE_BUGGY_TME_SUPPORT
    Open->DumpLimitReached = FALSE;
    Open->MaxFrameSize = 0;
    Open->WriterSN = 0;
    Open->ReaderSN = 0;
    Open->Size = 0;
    Open->SkipSentPackets = FALSE;
    Open->ReadEvent = NULL;

    //
    // we need to keep a counter of the pending IRPs
    // so that when the IRP_MJ_CLEANUP dispatcher gets called,
    // we can wait for those IRPs to be completed
    //
    Open->NumPendingIrps = 0;
    Open->ClosePending = FALSE;
    NdisAllocateSpinLock(&Open->OpenInUseLock);

    //
    //allocate the spinlock for the statistic counters
    //
    NdisAllocateSpinLock(&Open->CountersLock);

    //
    //  link up the request stored in our open block
    //
    for (i = 0 ; i < MAX_REQUESTS ; i++)
    {
        NdisInitializeEvent(&Open->Requests[i].InternalRequestCompletedEvent);

        ExInterlockedInsertTailList(&Open->RequestList, &Open->Requests[i].ListElement, &Open->RequestSpinLock);
    }

    NdisResetEvent(&Open->NdisOpenCloseCompleteEvent);

    // 
    // set the proper binding flags before trying to open the MAC
    //
    Open->AdapterBindingStatus = ADAPTER_BOUND;
    Open->AdapterHandleUsageCounter = 0;
    NdisAllocateSpinLock(&Open->AdapterHandleLock);

    //
    //  Try to open the MAC
    //
    TRACE_MESSAGE2(PACKET_DEBUG_LOUD, "Opening the device %ws, BindingContext=%p", DeviceExtension->AdapterName.Buffer, Open);

    returnStatus = STATUS_SUCCESS;

    NdisZeroMemory(&OpenParameters, sizeof(NDIS_OPEN_PARAMETERS));
    OpenParameters.Header.Type = NDIS_OBJECT_TYPE_OPEN_PARAMETERS;
    OpenParameters.Header.Revision = NDIS_OPEN_PARAMETERS_REVISION_1;
    OpenParameters.Header.Size = sizeof(NDIS_OPEN_PARAMETERS);
    OpenParameters.AdapterName = &DeviceExtension->AdapterName;
    OpenParameters.MediumArray = MediumArray;
    OpenParameters.MediumArraySize = sizeof(MediumArray) / sizeof(NDIS_MEDIUM);
    OpenParameters.SelectedMediumIndex = &Open->Medium;
    OpenParameters.FrameTypeArray = NULL;
    OpenParameters.FrameTypeArraySize = 0;
    //OpenParameters.FrameTypeArray = &FrameTypeArray[0];
    //OpenParameters.FrameTypeArraySize = sizeof(FrameTypeArray) / sizeof(NET_FRAME_TYPE);


    NDIS_DECLARE_PROTOCOL_OPEN_CONTEXT(OPEN_INSTANCE);
    Status = NdisOpenAdapterEx(g_NdisProtocolHandle, (NDIS_HANDLE)Open, &OpenParameters, NULL, &Open->AdapterHandle);

    //  NdisOpenAdapter(
    //      &Status,
    //      &ErrorStatus,
    //      &Open->AdapterHandle,
    //      &Open->Medium,
    //      MediumArray,
    //      NUM_NDIS_MEDIA,
    //      g_NdisProtocolHandle,
    //      Open,
    //      &DeviceExtension->AdapterName,
    //      0,
    //      NULL);

    TRACE_MESSAGE1(PACKET_DEBUG_LOUD, "Opened the device, Status=%x", Status);

    if (Status == NDIS_STATUS_PENDING)
    {
        NdisWaitEvent(&Open->NdisOpenCloseCompleteEvent, 0);

        if (!NT_SUCCESS(Open->OpenCloseStatus))
        {
            returnStatus = Open->OpenCloseStatus;
        }
        else
        {
            returnStatus = STATUS_SUCCESS;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //
        // request not pending, we know the result, and OpenComplete has not been called.
        //
        if (Status == NDIS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
        {
            returnStatus = STATUS_SUCCESS;
        }
        else
        {
            //
            // this is not completely correct, as we are converting an NDIS_STATUS to a NTSTATUS
            //
            returnStatus = Status;
        }
    }

    if (returnStatus == STATUS_SUCCESS)
    {
        ULONG localNumOpenedInstances;  
        //
        // complete the open
        //
        localNumOpenedInstances = InterlockedIncrement(&g_NumOpenedInstances);

        TRACE_MESSAGE1(PACKET_DEBUG_LOUD, "Opened Instances: %u", localNumOpenedInstances);

        // Get the absolute value of the system boot time.
        // This is used for timestamp conversion.
        TIME_SYNCHRONIZE(&G_Start_Time);

        returnStatus = NPF_GetDeviceMTU(Open, Irp, &Open->MaxFrameSize);

        if (!NT_SUCCESS(returnStatus))
        {
            //
            // Close the binding
            //
            NPF_CloseBinding(Open);
        }
    }

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(returnStatus))
    {
        NPF_ReleaseOpenInstanceResources(Open);
        //
        // Free the open instance itself
        //
        ExFreePool(Open);
    }
    else
    {
        //  Save or open here
        IrpSp->FileObject->FsContext = Open;
    }

    Irp->IoStatus.Status = returnStatus;
    Irp->IoStatus.Information = 0;
    IoCompleteRequest(Irp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);

    TRACE_EXIT();
    return returnStatus;
}

BOOLEAN NPF_StartUsingOpenInstance(IN POPEN_INSTANCE pOpen)
{
    BOOLEAN returnStatus;

    NdisAcquireSpinLock(&pOpen->OpenInUseLock);
    if (pOpen->ClosePending)
    {
        returnStatus = FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        returnStatus = TRUE;
        pOpen->NumPendingIrps ++;
    }
    NdisReleaseSpinLock(&pOpen->OpenInUseLock);

    return returnStatus;
}

VOID NPF_StopUsingOpenInstance(IN POPEN_INSTANCE pOpen)
{
    NdisAcquireSpinLock(&pOpen->OpenInUseLock);
    ASSERT(pOpen->NumPendingIrps > 0);
    pOpen->NumPendingIrps --;
    NdisReleaseSpinLock(&pOpen->OpenInUseLock);
}

VOID NPF_CloseOpenInstance(IN POPEN_INSTANCE pOpen)
{
    ULONG i = 0;
    NDIS_EVENT Event;

    ASSERT(KeGetCurrentIrql() == PASSIVE_LEVEL);

    NdisInitializeEvent(&Event);
    NdisResetEvent(&Event);

    NdisAcquireSpinLock(&pOpen->OpenInUseLock);

    pOpen->ClosePending = TRUE;

    while (pOpen->NumPendingIrps > 0)
    {
        NdisReleaseSpinLock(&pOpen->OpenInUseLock);
        NdisWaitEvent(&Event, 1);
        NdisAcquireSpinLock(&pOpen->OpenInUseLock);
    }

    NdisReleaseSpinLock(&pOpen->OpenInUseLock);
}


VOID NPF_ReleaseOpenInstanceResources(POPEN_INSTANCE pOpen)
{
    PKEVENT pEvent;
    UINT i;

    TRACE_ENTER();

    ASSERT(pOpen != NULL);
    ASSERT(KeGetCurrentIrql() == PASSIVE_LEVEL);

    TRACE_MESSAGE1(PACKET_DEBUG_LOUD, "Open= %p", pOpen);

    //NdisFreePacketPool(pOpen->PacketPool);
    NdisFreeNetBufferListPool(pOpen->PacketPool);

    //
    // Free the filter if it's present
    //
    if (pOpen->bpfprogram != NULL)
        ExFreePool(pOpen->bpfprogram);

    //
    // Jitted filters are supported on x86 (32bit) only
    // 
#ifdef _X86_
    // Free the jitted filter if it's present
    if (pOpen->Filter != NULL)
        BPF_Destroy_JIT_Filter(pOpen->Filter);
#endif //_X86_

    //
    // Dereference the read event.
    //

    if (pOpen->ReadEvent != NULL)
        ObDereferenceObject(pOpen->ReadEvent);

    //
    // free the buffer
    // NOTE: the buffer is fragmented among the various CPUs, but the base pointer of the
    // allocated chunk of memory is stored in the first slot (pOpen->CpuData[0])
    //
    if (pOpen->Size > 0)
        ExFreePool(pOpen->CpuData[0].Buffer);

    //
    // free the per CPU spinlocks
    //
    for (i = 0; i < g_NCpu; i++)
    {
        NdisFreeSpinLock(&pOpen->CpuData[i].BufferLock);
    }

    //
    // Free the string with the name of the dump file
    //
    if (pOpen->DumpFileName.Buffer != NULL)
        ExFreePool(pOpen->DumpFileName.Buffer);

    TRACE_EXIT();
}


//-------------------------------------------------------------------

VOID NPF_OpenAdapterCompleteEx(IN NDIS_HANDLE  ProtocolBindingContext, IN NDIS_STATUS  Status)
{
    POPEN_INSTANCE Open;
    PLIST_ENTRY RequestListEntry;
    PINTERNAL_REQUEST MaxSizeReq;
    NDIS_STATUS ReqStatus;

    TRACE_ENTER();

    Open = (POPEN_INSTANCE)ProtocolBindingContext;

    ASSERT(Open != NULL);

    if (Status != NDIS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
    {
        //
        // this is not completely correct, as we are converting an NDIS_STATUS to a NTSTATUS
        //
        Open->OpenCloseStatus = Status;
    }
    else
    {
        Open->OpenCloseStatus = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    }

    //
    // wake up the caller of NdisOpen, that is NPF_Open
    //
    NdisSetEvent(&Open->NdisOpenCloseCompleteEvent);

    TRACE_EXIT();
}

NTSTATUS NPF_GetDeviceMTU(IN POPEN_INSTANCE pOpen, IN PIRP  pIrp, OUT PUINT  pMtu)
{
    PLIST_ENTRY RequestListEntry;
    PINTERNAL_REQUEST MaxSizeReq;
    NDIS_STATUS ReqStatus;

    TRACE_ENTER();

    ASSERT(pOpen != NULL);
    ASSERT(pIrp != NULL);
    ASSERT(pMtu != NULL);

    // Extract a request from the list of free ones
    RequestListEntry = ExInterlockedRemoveHeadList(&pOpen->RequestList, &pOpen->RequestSpinLock);

    if (RequestListEntry == NULL)
    {
        //
        // THIS IS WRONG
        //

        //
        // Assume Ethernet
        //
        *pMtu = 1514;   
        TRACE_EXIT();
        return STATUS_SUCCESS;
    }

    MaxSizeReq = CONTAINING_RECORD(RequestListEntry, INTERNAL_REQUEST, ListElement);

    MaxSizeReq->Request.RequestType = NdisRequestQueryInformation;
    MaxSizeReq->Request.DATA.QUERY_INFORMATION.Oid = OID_GEN_MAXIMUM_TOTAL_SIZE;

    MaxSizeReq->Request.DATA.QUERY_INFORMATION.InformationBuffer = pMtu;
    MaxSizeReq->Request.DATA.QUERY_INFORMATION.InformationBufferLength = sizeof(*pMtu);

    NdisResetEvent(&MaxSizeReq->InternalRequestCompletedEvent);

    //  submit the request
    ReqStatus = NdisOidRequest(pOpen->AdapterHandle, &MaxSizeReq->Request);

    if (ReqStatus == NDIS_STATUS_PENDING)
    {
        NdisWaitEvent(&MaxSizeReq->InternalRequestCompletedEvent, 0);
        ReqStatus = MaxSizeReq->RequestStatus;
    }

    //
    // Put the request in the list of the free ones
    //
    ExInterlockedInsertTailList(&pOpen->RequestList, &MaxSizeReq->ListElement, &pOpen->RequestSpinLock);

    if (ReqStatus == NDIS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
    {
        TRACE_EXIT();
        return STATUS_SUCCESS;
    }
    else
    {
        //
        // THIS IS WRONG
        //

        //
        // Assume Ethernet
        //
        *pMtu = 1514;   

        TRACE_EXIT();
        return STATUS_SUCCESS;

        // return ReqStatus;
    }
}


//-------------------------------------------------------------------
NTSTATUS NPF_CloseAdapter(IN PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, IN PIRP Irp)
{
    POPEN_INSTANCE pOpen;
    PIO_STACK_LOCATION IrpSp;
    TRACE_ENTER();

    IrpSp = IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation(Irp);
    pOpen = IrpSp->FileObject->FsContext;

    ASSERT(pOpen != NULL);
    //
    // Free the open instance itself
    //
    ExFreePool(pOpen);

    Irp->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    Irp->IoStatus.Information = 0;
    IoCompleteRequest(Irp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);

    TRACE_EXIT();
    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------
NTSTATUS NPF_Cleanup(IN PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, IN PIRP Irp)
{
    POPEN_INSTANCE Open;
    NDIS_STATUS Status;
    PIO_STACK_LOCATION IrpSp;
    LARGE_INTEGER ThreadDelay;
    ULONG localNumOpenInstances;

    TRACE_ENTER();

    IrpSp = IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation(Irp);
    Open = IrpSp->FileObject->FsContext;

    TRACE_MESSAGE1(PACKET_DEBUG_LOUD, "Open = %p\n", Open);

    ASSERT(Open != NULL);

    NPF_CloseOpenInstance(Open);

    if (Open->ReadEvent != NULL)
        KeSetEvent(Open->ReadEvent, 0, FALSE);

    NPF_CloseBinding(Open);

    // NOTE:
    // code commented out because the kernel dump feature is disabled
    //
    //if (AdapterAlreadyClosing == FALSE)
    //{

    //  
    //   Unfreeze the consumer
    //  
    //  if(Open->mode & MODE_DUMP)
    //      NdisSetEvent(&Open->DumpEvent);
    //  else
    //      KeSetEvent(Open->ReadEvent,0,FALSE);

    //  //
    //  // If this instance is in dump mode, complete the dump and close the file
    //  //
    //  if((Open->mode & MODE_DUMP) && Open->DumpFileHandle != NULL)
    //  {
    //      NTSTATUS wres;

    //      ThreadDelay.QuadPart = -50000000;

    //      //
    //      // Wait the completion of the thread
    //      //
    //      wres = KeWaitForSingleObject(Open->DumpThreadObject,
    //          UserRequest,
    //          KernelMode,
    //          TRUE,
    //          &ThreadDelay);

    //      ObDereferenceObject(Open->DumpThreadObject);

    //      //
    //      // Flush and close the dump file
    //      //
    //      NPF_CloseDumpFile(Open);
    //  }
    //}


    //
    // release all the resources
    //
    NPF_ReleaseOpenInstanceResources(Open);

    //  IrpSp->FileObject->FsContext = NULL;

    //
    // Decrease the counter of open instances
    //
    localNumOpenInstances = InterlockedDecrement(&g_NumOpenedInstances);
    TRACE_MESSAGE1(PACKET_DEBUG_LOUD, "Opened Instances: %u", localNumOpenInstances);

    if (localNumOpenInstances == 0)
    {
        //
        // Force a synchronization at the next NPF_Open().
        // This hopefully avoids the synchronization issues caused by hibernation or standby.
        //
        TIME_DESYNCHRONIZE(&G_Start_Time);
    }


    //
    // and complete the IRP with status success
    //
    Irp->IoStatus.Information = 0;
    Irp->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    IoCompleteRequest(Irp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);

    TRACE_EXIT();

    return(STATUS_SUCCESS);
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------

VOID NPF_CloseAdapterCompleteEx(IN NDIS_HANDLE  ProtocolBindingContext)
{
    POPEN_INSTANCE Open;
    PIRP Irp;

    TRACE_ENTER();

    Open = (POPEN_INSTANCE)ProtocolBindingContext;

    ASSERT(Open != NULL);

    TRACE_MESSAGE1(PACKET_DEBUG_LOUD, "Open= %p", Open);

    NdisSetEvent(&Open->NdisOpenCloseCompleteEvent);

    TRACE_EXIT();
    return;
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------

NDIS_STATUS NPF_NetPowerChange(IN NDIS_HANDLE ProtocolBindingContext, IN PNET_PNP_EVENT_NOTIFICATION pNetPnPEvent)
{
    TRACE_ENTER();

    TIME_DESYNCHRONIZE(&G_Start_Time);
    TIME_SYNCHRONIZE(&G_Start_Time);

    TRACE_EXIT();
    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------

NDIS_STATUS NPF_BindAdapterEx(IN NDIS_HANDLE ProtocolDriverContext, IN NDIS_HANDLE BindContext, IN PNDIS_BIND_PARAMETERS BindParameters)
{
    NTSTATUS ntStatus = NDIS_STATUS_SUCCESS;
    int a = 1;
    a ++;
    TRACE_ENTER();
    TRACE_EXIT();
    return ntStatus;
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------


NDIS_STATUS NPF_UnbindAdapterEx(IN  NDIS_HANDLE         UnbindContext, IN  NDIS_HANDLE         ProtocolBindingContext)
{
    NTSTATUS Status;
    POPEN_INSTANCE Open = (POPEN_INSTANCE)ProtocolBindingContext;

    TRACE_ENTER();

    ASSERT(Open != NULL);

    //
    // The following code has been disabled bcause the kernel dump feature has been disabled.
    //
    ////
    //// Awake a possible pending read on this instance
    //// TODO should be ok.
    ////
    //  if(Open->mode & MODE_DUMP)
    //      NdisSetEvent(&Open->DumpEvent);
    //  else
    if (Open->ReadEvent != NULL)
        KeSetEvent(Open->ReadEvent, 0, FALSE);

    //
    // The following code has been disabled bcause the kernel dump feature has been disabled.
    //
    ////
    //// If this instance is in dump mode, complete the dump and close the file
    //// TODO needs to be checked again.
    ////
    //  if((Open->mode & MODE_DUMP) && Open->DumpFileHandle != NULL)
    //      NPF_CloseDumpFile(Open);

    Status = NDIS_STATUS_SUCCESS;

    NPF_CloseBinding(Open);

    TRACE_EXIT();
    return Status;
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------

VOID NPF_ResetComplete(IN NDIS_HANDLE  ProtocolBindingContext, IN NDIS_STATUS  Status)
{
    POPEN_INSTANCE Open;
    PIRP Irp;

    PLIST_ENTRY ResetListEntry;

    TRACE_ENTER();

    Open = (POPEN_INSTANCE)ProtocolBindingContext;

    //
    //  remove the reset IRP from the list
    //
    ResetListEntry = ExInterlockedRemoveHeadList(&Open->ResetIrpList, &Open->RequestSpinLock);

    Irp = CONTAINING_RECORD(ResetListEntry, IRP, Tail.Overlay.ListEntry);

    Irp->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    IoCompleteRequest(Irp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);

    TRACE_EXIT();

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've definitely hit across an interesting problem with WinPcap.  Its protocol driver (NPF) expects to be able to open an adapter whenever it wants.  When paired with Wireshark, it will do this frequently — it's typical to see NPF open and close the same adapter dozens of times just while the Wireshark GUI is loading.  It's even possible to see NPF have multiple bindings to the same adapter *simultaneously*.

The rough equivalent of this in NDIS 6.x is the `NdisReEnumerateProtocolBindings` function.  What this does is queue up a workitem to call into your protocol' `ProtocolBindAdapterEx` handler for each adapter that is marked as bound in the registry, but isn't currently bound in NDIS.  (I.e., for each adapter that INetCfg finds a bindpath to that does not already have an open handle.)

However, due to the large impedance between NPF's API and how NDIS regards binding, you'll need to tackle a few issues:

1. **Multiple simultaneous bindings to the same adapter**.  (This is a rarely-used feature; NPF is one of two protocols that I know use this, so it's not really discussed much in the MSDN documentation.)  The only way to get multiple simultaneous bindings in NDIS 6.x is to call `NdisOpenAdapterEx` twice *within the same `ProtocolBindAdapterEx` call*.  That's going to be challenging, because NPF's model is to open a new binding whenever an API call comes in from usermode; it doesn't know in advance how many handles will need to be opened.

   If another bind request comes in, you can attempt to close all previous handles to that adapter (transparently to the NPF API[!]), call `NdisReEnumerateProtocolBindings`, then open N+1 handles in your upcoming `ProtocolBindAdpaterEx` handler.  But this is brittle.

   You can also try and merge all API calls to the same adapter.  If a second bind request comes in, just route it to the pre-existing binding to that adapter.  This might be difficult, depending on how NPF's internals work.  (I'm not allowed to read NPF source code; I can't say.)

   Finally, the cheesy solution is to just allocate two (or three) binding handles always, and keep the extras cached in case Wireshark needs them.  This is cheap to implement, but still a bit fragile, since you can't really know if Wireshark will want more handles than you pre-allocated.
2. **Missing `INetCfg` bindings**.  NDIS 5.x protocols are allowed to bind to an adapter even if the protocol isn't actually supposed to be bound (according to `INetCfg`).  Wireshark uses this to get itself bound to all sorts of random adapters, without worrying too much about whether `INetCfg` agrees that NPF should be bound.  Once you convert to NDIS 6.x, the rules are enforced strictly, and you'll need to make sure that your protocol's INF has a `LowerRange` keyword for each type of adapter you want to bind over.  (I.e., the NPF protocol should show up in the Adapter Properties dialog box.)
3. **Asynchronous bindings**.  The `NdisReEnumerateProtocolBindings` model is that you call it, and NDIS will make an attempt to bind your protocol to all bindable adapters.  If the adapter isn't bindable for some reason (perhaps it's in a low-power state, or it's being surprise-removed), then NDIS will simply not call your protocol back.  It's going to be tough to know exactly when to give up and return failure to the usermode NPF API, since you don't get a callback saying "you *won't* bind to this adapter".  You may be able to use `NetEventBindsComplete`, but frankly that's kind of a dodgy, ill-defined event and I'm not convinced it's bulletproof.  I'd put in a timeout, then use the NetEvent as a hint to cut the timeout short.

Finally, I just wanted to note that, although you said that you wanted to minimize the amount of churn in WinPcap, you might want to consider repackaging its driver as an NDIS LWF.  LWFs were designed for exactly this purpose, so they tend to fit better with NPF's needs.  (In particular, LWFs can see native 802.11 traffic, can get more accurate data without going through the loopback hack, and are quite a bit simpler than protocols.)

Comment: 1) Multiple simultaneous bindings to the same adapter: why did you say “merge all API calls to the same adapter” is difficult? I thought it is a better way than others? And why did you say "I'm not allowed to read NPF source code", I'm afraid WinPcap is a open source software?

Comment: 2)Missing INetCfg bindings. You are right. I found that now I must provide a inf file in order to bind my driver to each 

adapter.  At last, it seems that I have two ways, go ahead with my protocol driver porting job or change to LWF driver, I am 

a 2013 GSoC student for Nmap and have nearly 2 or 3 weeks for this. Which way do you suggest? Thanks.

Comment: I can't read NPF source code because my employer would prohibit it.  (I work for Microsoft, where I currently happen to own NDIS and INetCfg.)  Merging API calls might be easier than I imagine; it depends on how much state the NPF API pushes onto a binding.  If the API can set a binding to promiscuous mode, that would affect all others using the same binding, unless you do your own packet filtering.

Comment: 2)  You have only 2-3 weeks to get familiar with Wireshark, NPF, NDIS, and kernel programming?  This one's going to be tough!  A LWF is the right architectural decision for a packet capturing device, but I gather that NMAP is more interested in packet injection.  For that, a protocol will suit you fine too.  I'm not sure how sophisticated NPF actually is; you might find it's easier to start with the NDIS6 sample driver "NDISPROT" and graft on the NPF API from there.  At least NDISPROT works well from an NDIS perspective.

Comment: The whole GSoC project will last 3 months, now one month has passed. I want to finish the porting job as soon as possbile, because there are still other features I need to add to WinPcap.. Nmap focues on packet capturing, also some ethernet packet sending. Maybe LWF can do this too.

Comment: I know that Wireshark can set an adapter to promiscuous mode, but will Wireshark open the same adapter in different modes? I didn't see this usage? When will an adapter be opened for multiple times?

Comment: LWFs can do nearly anything that a protocol can do.  They can send packets, capture or modify received packets, inject "fake" received packets, and drop or modify "real" send packets.  For "manipulation" or "monitoring" type stuff, LWFs work well.  (Protocols are good for implementing, well, network protocols.)

Comment: The point of the promiscuous example is just to illustrate why it might be nontrivial to "merge" NPF handles onto a single NDIS handle.  If NPF hands have contradictory state set on them (p-mode vs not p-mode), then you have to do work to fake it in your handle-merging code.  Wireshark opens adapters multiple times for brief moments during boot.  It's hard to catch it unless you set a specific breakpoint in your driver.